# MVVM Light SimpleIoc Unregister instance failed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I'm working on a WPF project with MVVM Light. This application runs on the system tray and generates a Windows with a ViewModel associated.

When the user closes Windows, I have a ViewModelLocator to release his instance ViewModel associated.
There are multi-instances ViewModel at the same time, I can't remove all instance, just the one associated with closed Window

```
public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        public ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<CollectorViewModel>();

        public static T GetNewInstance<T>(string uniqueKey)
        {
            var model =  ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<T>(uniqueKey);
            return model;
        }

        public static T GetInstance<T>()
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<T>();
        }       

        public static void Cleanup(string uniqueKey)
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister(uniqueKey);
        }
    }


public class CollectorViewModel
{
        ~CollectorViewModel()
        {
             //relase some resources
        }
}
```

I tried to release the instance by this code. I'm sure that I passed correct uniqueKey for the instance

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister(uniqueKey);
```

2nd try doesn't have the effect.

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<CollectorViewModel>(myInstance);
```

But when I check, it's always there.

```
SimpleIoc.Default.GetAllInstances(typeof(CollectorViewModel));
```

The question: How to release the instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question: How to release the instance?

If you register the type like this:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<CollectorViewModel>();
```

...you unregister it like this, i.e without any key:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<CollectorViewModel>();
```

This works as expected:

```
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

SimpleIoc.Default.Register<CollectorViewModel>();
Debug.Assert(SimpleIoc.Default.GetAllInstances<CollectorViewModel>().Count() == 1);
SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<CollectorViewModel>();
Debug.Assert(SimpleIoc.Default.GetAllInstances<CollectorViewModel>().Count() == 0);
```

If you get an instance with a key like this:

```
var instance = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<CollectorViewModel>("xyz");
```

...you unregister this instance like this:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<CollectorViewModel>("xyz");
```

This also works as expected:

```
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

SimpleIoc.Default.Register<CollectorViewModel>();
Debug.Assert(SimpleIoc.Default.GetAllInstances<CollectorViewModel>().Count() == 1);
var instance = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<CollectorViewModel>("xyz");
Debug.Assert(SimpleIoc.Default.GetAllInstances<CollectorViewModel>().Count() ==2);
SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<CollectorViewModel>("xyz");
Debug.Assert(SimpleIoc.Default.GetAllInstances<CollectorViewModel>().Count() == 1);
```

Comment: I think if I follow your code, it will release all instances of CollectorViewModel, I only want to release the instance with the UniKey indicated...

Comment: In the sample, I have SimpleIoc.Default.Register<CollectorViewModel>() to register type CollectorViewModel and GetNewInstance<T>(string uniqueKey) to generate a new instance... I can't remove all because ViewModel is associated with a windows. If Windows is closed, i release his ViewModel. There are multi Windows are opened at the same time...

Comment: finalizer can't be called because ViewModel is always referenced in SimpleIoc

Comment: In fact, when I call GetNewInstance, there is an instance of registered type in  SimpleIoc, so to answer your question abt how to register the instance, I can't answer. It's added automatically.

Comment: My question is about how to remove a single instance.... not all instance of registered type..

Comment: See my edited answer. You just call Unregister with the appropriate type and key.

Comment: Your answer like exactly what I tried in my question. By your answer, I think about the version of dll, I had :CommonServiceLocator 1.3 and MvvmLightLibs 5.2

Comment: What? My code certainly works. `Debug.Assert` would have thrown otherwise.

Comment: Which version you used?

Comment: @ThierryV: 2.0.2 And MvvmLight 5.4.1.

Comment: I understand the problem. I write it down later and should give you an upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

This line code creates the problem because it wants to a **exact** type, a key of the instance isn't enough for SimpleIoc to find the instance.

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister(uniqueKey);
```

For example, in my project,

```
public class A

public class B: A
```

if you want to release an instance of B, you must do:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<B>(unique_key_of_instance_B);
```

It can't work even you use class A

<strike>SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister(unique_key_of_instance_B);</strike>

So, to update ViewModelLocator class:

```
public static void Cleanup<T>(string uniqueKey) where T:class
{
      SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<T>(uniqueKey);
}
```

Comment: What’s the difference between this and the solution I have already suggested? You should specify a type argument and key as I mentioned in my answer.